# allow apache to run a python program

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd

How do I grant write permission to Apache only for a specific directory?  I want to have a user enter (validated) information [a stock symbol] into a form and have matplotlib generate a plot that would be displayed on the page.

Comment: You can do that without write permissions, by telling matplotlib to `savefig` (e.g. an SVG) into a string buffer and delivering that. Also, this actually sounds a lot like you'd want to leave the data rendering to the browser – there's might tools for that, for example [Bokeh](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/) is a nice Python library to send data to a web browser, which then makes exactly the visualization the programmer wanted – instead of doing the visualization in Matplotlib, which is very inefficient/slow, and then sending it as picture to the browser.

Comment: also not that the title of your question is "allow apache to *run* a program" and the first sentence is "allow apache to write". Both different things, and will be handled differently both by Apache, and by SE Linux (assuming this is Linux. Can you confirm?)

Comment: So, maybe we start with what your **actual** question is: Is it 1. *how do I run a Python program from Apache?* **OR** 2. *I know how to run a Python program from Apache, but I have permission problems not allowing me to run it. How to fix that?* **OR** 3. *I'm running a Python program from Apache, but it can't write to a directory. How do I fix that?* **Let's focus on one question first.**